# What wireless protocols can be used with arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, library, wireless

Before you close this saying it's not related to programming. It is related to programming since i'm using it and asking about libraries.

What are the common types of communication protocols and their libraries? Theres WiFi which uses esp8266 etc. Zigbee which can be used with XBee, Bluetooth which can be used with esp32 and others.
What are a list of wireless protocols and chips and libraries for those wireless communications? (This list will be compiled by multiple people hopefully so its okay if you don't know the library or chip but protocol is good) thank you and hopefully no take down <3

Comment: Any and all protocols can be used if you can find/build/program the interface to them.

Comment: I'm asking what protocols exist. Link a list?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wireless_data_standards

Comment: this question is not arduino specific

Comment: Arduino can use all wireless protocols both in existence today and which yet will be invented in the future. There is no limit to wireless protocols which may be used with Arduino. The correct answer is: all of the protocols.

Answer (score 3):

Arduino allows you to connect external peripherals (via I2C, SPI, UART, I/O) and shields.

It'll be impossible to list them all, as you can even make your own; but here an overview of the most common I can think off:

- WiFi
- Bluetooth
- LoRa
- Zigbee
- Z-wave
- RF (433mhz)
- InfraRed
- GSM/LTE

It'll be a trade-off between signal range, power usage, delay and bandwidth.

Do note that your question in this way is quite broad. If you want to use this to start your own wireless proejct, you can follow these steps (, but do note that we expect one to do some research/tests himself before posting a question):

1. Find a tranmission layer applicable for your project based on requirements.
2. Find Arduino compatible hardware (if none found; make your own or find another transmission layer / adjust requirements)
3. Find libraries/examples of this hardware being used with Arduino.
4. Buy the hardware (this is not step 1!)
5. Use the found sources and make your project reality.